# Сравнить значение столбца с переменной

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо сравнить значение из таблицы Mysql с переменной в php. Это необходимо для создания "вайт листа". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть переменная $chat, где содержится id профиля собеседника, нужно сравнить это значение с telegram_id из БД и если оно совпадает то что-то делать
.

Comment: это заданием нам?)) не понимаю

Comment: @Jean-Claude нет, я не понимаю как это реализовать, вот хочу чтобы подсказали

Comment: делаете запрос к БД, извлекаете данные, затем сравниваете значение https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php